# Installing new thermostat without a C wire. Can I use my heater/R wire instead? Random 13V as well

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'm installing a thermostat, but I don't appear to have a C wire. My old thermostat had R/RH,Y,G,and W. It's an AC system that was setup before I got here. The actual AC unit is a long way away and inaccessible because of how the community was built.

I never use my heater and when I measured the voltage, it was 24V (the same as C), so can I use that instead? I read that you can use the fan wire, but I turn my fan to 'ON' at night. I thought if I never use my heater, why not use that? Or am I missing something.

I also have a random blue wire bundled behind my wall, but it didn't power on my thermostat. It read 13V in my multimeter.

[image: Image to my blower and the wires I see]

[image: Image to my blower and the wires I see]

Comment: Is the heater unit/air handler accessible?  Normally, the thermostat wires go to there first, not the A/C outdoor unit (condenser/compressor)

Comment: yes! after your comment, I went looking around my house and found where it was installed. I added an image I took of it to my post! Thank you!

Comment: What model is the air handler/heater?  The fat blue wires *look* like they'd be coming from the 24VAC transformer, but I'd need to see a wiring diagram to be sure

Comment: It's a goodman on all ends. I attached a picture to my post above. I think its a ACNF24-0816, i have a multimeter, what should i connect the other end to

Comment: I looked into it a little more today and it looks like that blue wire I found tucked wasn't actually hooked to anything. When I read 13v earlier, I must have been reading the other wire I used (the red). So i can use that wire if needed, but is there a way to find the 24v source? What two wires would I use to test against each other. Looks like the big brown isnt hooked to anything, and there's the blue green and red big wires

Comment: test the big blue and big red wires together -- you should have 24VAC across those two, as well as 24VAC from the big blue to the little red.  (The 13VAC reading you got was a result of capacitive coupling.)  BTW: the manual for your air handler is available [here](http://www.goodmanmfg.com/docs/librariesprovider6/default-document-library/ss-gacnf51de270022fa6258827eff0300754798.pdf?sfvrsn=0)

Comment: Thanks! Giving it a test when I get off work! If those two measure 24v, would it be safe to assume the big blue is common? So looking the unused small blue wire on my thermostat line to that would work?

Comment: that sounds about right, provided it's going to the secondary of the 24VAC transformer.